# The code is working but if you see the last part of code in which 'des' is written not shown anything in csv file

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

The code is working but if you see the last part of code in which 'des' is written not shown anything in csv file I am very thankful if you solve it in csv file they show nothing.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
baseurl='https://www.tradesupply.eu'
headers ={
    'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.114 Safari/537.36'
}
r =requests.get('https://www.tradesupply.eu/categories.html?name=drum&type=simple')
soup=BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
tra = soup.find_all('li',class_='products__item')
productlinks=[]
Title=[]
Brand=[]
Colour=[]
Printer=[]
Code=[]
Des=[]
for links in tra:
    for link in links.find_all('a',href=True):
        comp=baseurl+link['href']
        productlinks.append(comp)

for link in productlinks:
    r =requests.get(link,headers=headers)
    soup=BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
    title=soup.find('h1').text
    Title.append(title)
    brand=soup.find('div',class_="product__brand").text
    Brand.append(brand)
    colour=soup.find('div',class_="product__colour").text 
    Colour.append(colour)
    printer=soup.find('div',class_="product__printer-manufacturer").text
    Printer.append(printer)
    code=soup.find('div',class_='l-product__codeblock').text.strip()
    Code.append(code)
    des=soup.find('div',class_="padding").text
    Des.append(des)
    

df = pd.DataFrame(
    
    {"Title": Title, "brand": Brand,"colour":Colour,"printer":Printer,"code":Code,"des":Des}
)
df.to_csv('pd .csv', index=False, encoding='utf-8')
```

Comment: I cannot replicate - when I run your code, the `csv` file is saved and I see `des` column populated in my LibreOffice.

Comment: works for me too. but in some systems you'd better avoid spaces in your file names. have you tried naming your file `pd.csv`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
baseurl='https://www.tradesupply.eu'
headers ={
    'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.114 Safari/537.36'
}
r =requests.get('https://www.tradesupply.eu/categories.html?name=drum&type=simple')
soup=BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
tra = soup.find_all('li',class_='products__item')
productlinks=[]
Title=[]
Brand=[]
Colour=[]
Printer=[]
Code=[]
Des=[]
for links in tra:
    for link in links.find_all('a',href=True):
        comp=baseurl+link['href']
        productlinks.append(comp)

for link in productlinks:
    r =requests.get(link,headers=headers)
    soup=BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
    title=soup.find('h1').text
    Title.append(title)
    brand=soup.find('div',class_="product__brand").text
    Brand.append(brand)
    colour=soup.find('div',class_="product__colour").text 
    Colour.append(colour)
    printer=soup.find('div',class_="product__printer-manufacturer").text
    Printer.append(printer)
    code=soup.find('div',class_='l-product__codeblock').text.strip()
    Code.append(code)
    des=soup.find('div',class_="padding").text.strip()
    Des.append(des)
    

df = pd.DataFrame(
    
    {"Title": Title, "brand": Brand,"colour":Colour,"printer":Printer,"code":Code,"des":Des}
)
df.to_csv('pd .csv', index=False, encoding='utf-8')
```